# Android drawing to bitmap canvas slow

Tags: android, performance, canvas, bitmap, imageview

Scenario is I have an ImageView that fills the phone screen.  Every so often based on touch events I draw an offscreen bitmap and display it on the ImageView.

Code to do the display is

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(Globals.screenWidth,Globals.screenHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
```

Then a bunch of paint settings, drawrects, and font outputs.

Once the bitmap/canvas is updated I show it onscreen by calling

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mainView);
iv.setImageBitmap(b);
```

This works but is slow.  There are not a lot of drawrects and font updates (maybe at most 100 drawrects and 5 or 6 lines of text), but it can take up to 400 ms for it to draw.  When it should seem instant to the user when they touch the screen.

Any other ways of getting an offscreen bitmap and/or canvas to display FAST onscreen?

Comment: Cache Bitmap b, every time create a new Canvas

Comment: If there is nothing you can do with the drawing, caching and reusing is the next to try. If you think drawing func has some problem, you can go to `code review stack exchange`

Comment: The contents of the bitmap change each time the user touches the screen, so no caching is possible.  Are calls to drawText, drawRect and setting paint colors etc always slow?  It seems like drawing to an offscreen bitmap and then copying to the onscreen display should be the fastest way.  It is in most other languages I have used.  I am a relative android newbie though.

Comment: just make a custom view and draw your bitmap followed by any drawing code you want...